# Problems in running a script.sh in Ubuntu app Windows10

Tags: bash, loops, ubuntu

I'm trying to learn how to code. I have to say that I'm using the Ubuntu app on the Windows system, so I don't know if my problems are related to this system.
I established these variables in the terminal

```
FOLDER="/mnt/c/Users/franc/Desktop/nuova"
species=mm10
fragmentsize=200
window=200
gap=200
output="/mnt/c/Users/franc/Desktop/nuova/sicer"
```

and then I wrote this loop

```
#!/bin/bash
for fq in $FOLDER/*.bam 
do
bedtools bamtobed -i  "$fq" >  "${fq%.bam}.bed"
sicer -t ${fq%.bam}.bed \
-s $species \
-f $fragmentsize \
-w $window \
-g $gap \
-o $output 
echo "DONE"
done
```

Basically I want the files in the FOLDER to be transformed in "${fq%.bam}.bed" and then I want to run sicer tool on these new files.
If I copy and paste these commands, on the terminal, everything goes fine but if I save the loop as script.sh and I try to run the script I obtain different errors.
Of course, I made the script executable with `chmod +x` and I also changed the syntax of the script using `awk '{ sub("\r$", ""); print }' myscript.sh > myscript1.sh` since I edited it in Windows(otherwise ubuntu fails to open it).
But when I launch the script containing the loop, it says that it is not able to open the files in the FOLDER (`Failed to open BAM file /*.bam` or `BAD permission denied`). I tried both to open it just giving the command `./myscript1.sh`  or also using `sudo ./myscript1.sh`.
What I'm missing? I have in some way link the variable I establish in the terminal to a new variable in the script saved?
thanks
Francesca

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to export the variables so that they'll be inherited by the shell process running the script.

```
export FOLDER="/mnt/c/Users/franc/Desktop/nuova"
export species=mm10
export fragmentsize=200
export window=200
export gap=200
export output="/mnt/c/Users/franc/Desktop/nuova/sicer"
```